# How to solve BuildJobExitNonZero on Digital Ocean

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel-8, digital-ocean

Hi guys its my first time trying digital ocean,
I am deploying my app via Launch App and my code are hosted on github however when i try importing the code and building i am getting the below error and i have no idea what that is

Please help

```html
2021-08-03T21:47:06.796342084Z => Initializing build
2021-08-03T21:47:06.832099453Z => Retrieving source code to /workspace
2021-08-03T21:47:06.860459803Z => Selecting branch "main"
2021-08-03T21:47:09.561399472Z => Checking out commit "9be192339cd0a8c93919eaf5959bd43c5ff06927"
2021-08-03T21:47:12.318858786Z => Got source_dir: /
2021-08-03T21:47:12.344366201Z => Using workspace root /workspace
2021-08-03T21:47:12.414846752Z 
2021-08-03T21:47:12.414907116Z => Building app using buildpacks
2021-08-03T21:47:12.704652275Z => Injecting app environment variables:
2021-08-03T21:47:12.704707986Z      QUEUE_CONNECTION DB_HOST SESSION_LIFETIME TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID SENTRY_TRACES_SAMPLE_RATE APP_URL SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN MAIL_MAILER TEXTTAWK_ENVIRONMENT DB_PASSWORD API_SECRET TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER PERSONAL_CLIENT_ID MAIL_USERNAME MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS PERSONAl_CLIENT_SECRET MULTI_DB_ENABLED BROADCAST_DRIVER APP_ENV GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID EXPANDED_LOGGING ERROR_EMAIL MAIL_PASSWORD GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET APP_NAME TRUSTED_PROXIES MAIL_HOST DB_CONNECTION APP_DEBUG DB_USERNAME GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI APP_KEY CACHE_DRIVER MAIL_ENCRYPTION SESSION_DRIVER INTERNAL_QUEUE_ENABLED MAIL_FROM_NAME DB_PORT DB_DATABASE MAIL_PORT TEXTTAWK_ORGANIZATION_ID
2021-08-03T21:47:12.736297358Z => Configuring custom build command to be run at the end of the build:
2021-08-03T21:47:12.761828497Z      composer install
2021-08-03T21:47:13.365839056Z => Running buildpack detection
2021-08-03T21:47:13.365923629Z 
2021-08-03T21:47:14.074627212Z heroku/nodejs-engine       0.5.0
2021-08-03T21:47:14.074682595Z digitalocean/node          0.3.4
2021-08-03T21:47:14.074757668Z digitalocean/php-appdetect 0.0.3
2021-08-03T21:47:14.074803894Z heroku/php                 0.188.4
2021-08-03T21:47:14.075038595Z digitalocean/procfile      0.0.3
2021-08-03T21:47:14.075058351Z digitalocean/custom        0.1.0
2021-08-03T21:47:14.202672749Z 
2021-08-03T21:47:14.202717224Z For documentation on the buildpacks used to build your app, please see:
2021-08-03T21:47:14.202743590Z    Node.js: https://do.co/apps-buildpack-node
2021-08-03T21:47:14.202798824Z    PHP: https://do.co/apps-buildpack-php
2021-08-03T21:47:14.818696983Z 
2021-08-03T21:47:14.818882813Z => Building app
2021-08-03T21:47:14.818924263Z 
2021-08-03T21:47:15.093655477Z ---> Node.js Buildpack
2021-08-03T21:47:15.108387965Z ---> Installing toolbox
2021-08-03T21:47:15.129668030Z ---> - jq
2021-08-03T21:47:15.847171368Z ---> - yj
2021-08-03T21:47:16.137897473Z ---> Getting Node version
2021-08-03T21:47:16.185826122Z ---> Resolving Node version
2021-08-03T21:47:18.820896954Z ---> Downloading and extracting Node v12.22.4
2021-08-03T21:47:33.310168979Z ---> Parsing package.json
2021-08-03T21:47:34.458500684Z ---> No file to start server
2021-08-03T21:47:34.458547440Z ---> either use 'docker run' to start container or add index.js or server.js
2021-08-03T21:47:34.543028305Z Error: package-lock.json does not exist. Please commit either a package-lock.json or yarn.lock file to your repository and try again.
2021-08-03T21:47:34.543513537Z project does not contain a package manager lockfile
2021-08-03T21:47:34.546474624Z [31;1mERROR: [0mfailed to build: exit status 1
2021-08-03T21:47:37.973947707Z 
2021-08-03T21:47:37.974088341Z For documentation on the buildpacks used to build your app, please see:
2021-08-03T21:47:37.974111872Z    Node.js: https://do.co/apps-buildpack-node
2021-08-03T21:47:37.974199168Z    PHP: https://do.co/apps-buildpack-php
2021-08-03T21:47:37.977558349Z 
2021-08-03T21:47:37.977966439Z [31m ! Build failed (145)[0m
```

Comment: you got  js error, non a php one.

Comment: Well its a php app and has no support for js, digital ocean should automatically detect that, my quest is question is it failing on js@N69S

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error and fixed it a different way. Since the error said "package-lock.json does not exist.", I added a package-lock.json file by running the `npm install` command in the root directory of the app, the one with the package.json file. After that the app deployed successfully.

Answer (score -2):

For anyone who might face this same challenge in the future,
for me the problem was "package.json"

if you deploying a Laravel API you need to delete the package.json file from your project. For me that was the issue that was preventing my project from building

Happy coding